# Xcode - Getting a cell to display new text after a touch event which makes it expand

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to have a dynamic table which expands on click to reveal some other content. I've got to the point where the table is populated with information from an NSMutableArray. I can also press each cell and it expands to double the size. Now, the next step, which is proving to be somewhat troublesome is to get it to display new/alternative text when they click on the cell. First of all, here's my setup method:

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        NSString *cellValue = [cellContent objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;

    }

    return cell;
}
```

and after this, I have the method where the cell expands on press:

```
    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // If our cell is selected, return double height
    if([self cellIsSelected:indexPath]) {
        return kCellHeight * 2.0;
        [cellContent replaceObjectAtIndex:[self cellIsSelected:indexPath] withObject:@"NEW STUFF HERE"];
}
```

I must be going about this in the wrong way as nothing changes when I touch the cell. How do I get it to display new/alternative text on touch? Any help would be super, I think it's likely to be something quite easy, but I can't see it at the moment.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second method is only triggered when the cell is built or rebuilt. You need to explicitly ask it to refresh itself in the following method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

And then within that method, you can call

```
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

and now your redraw methods will be triggered, so you can handle whatever you want there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @iBlue - I've implemented what you suggested and it updates my value no problem, but now it makes the transition when pressing the cell look really laggy, is there a certain place in the method I should look to set this value? I will accept your answer though as it has addressed my initial problem.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by laggy? And surely you can animate the change.

Comment: I mean it kind of jerks as I press on the cell, and isn't as smooth as when it expanded previously (I guess as it's showing the change of text as well as the cell shift at the same time). Not to worry, it works okay for its purpose.